# TSQL: Table type not being handled as temp table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Why is a table type not being handled as temp table?

Is it possible to have the table type available in exec context?

This code works:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[bl]
    @bl type_bl READONLY  
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    INTO #table2 
    FROM @bl

    EXEC('SELECT * FROM #table2')
END
```

Why does this code not work?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[bl]
    @bl type_bl READONLY  
AS
BEGIN
    EXEC('SELECT * FROM @bl')
END
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second example doesn't work because the nested scope created by `exec()` cannot access variables like `@bl` in the higher scope.

From [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/variables-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#declaring-a-transact-sql-variable):

> the nested scope created for execution of sp_executesql does not have access to the variable declared in the higher scope and returns and error.

If you need to access `@bl` from within the nested `exec()` scope, insert the contents of the table variable into a temp table and reference that temp table in your `exec()` call. The temp table can be accessed by scopes nested within the scope that created it.

Answer (score 5):

Since your using [`EXEC()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) which essentially executes dynamic SQL, the call itself is being made from a different scope from the rest of your code, so your `@bl` variable doesn't exist.

As a result, you'll need to use some mechanism such as a temp table (as your example demonstrates) to gain access to it within the `EXEC()` call, although I'd recommend avoiding the use of dynamic SQL unless you have a very specific reason for using it.

Comment: My "very specific reason" is actually a very simple one, the inserted table name has to be dynamic. Unfortunately there is this crazy limitation that dynamic table names can be achieved only via dynamic sql. Calling this a "specific reason" is insincere.

Comment: Dynamic SQL can very often be abused/misused as a mechanism for making some operations _appear_ easier (when in actuality there could be both security and performance implications related to them). This is why I included the disclaimer of avoiding it if possible.